# Terraform - GCP adding IP section on google_compute_vpn_gateway

Tags: google-cloud-platform, terraform

Trying to make a VPN Gateway using Terraform and I need to refer my reserved GCP IP when creating it.

There's nothing on the [**GCP documentation**](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/google/latest/docs/resources/compute_vpn_gateway) that refers to such a thing. Only arguments you may set are `network` / `region`

While in GUI it'll prompt you asking for an IP Address:

[image]

I've added the terraform snippet here

```
// Provisions a VPN Gateway
resource "google_compute_vpn_gateway" "target_gateway" {
  name    = "vpn-network"
  network = google_compute_network.vpn.id
  region  = var.gcp_region
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[From reference](https://github.com/terraform-google-modules/terraform-google-vpn) you can use:

`vpn_gw_ip`

As input to set your reserved IP

Comment: This sadly doesn't work and return `An argument named "vpn_gw_ip" is not expected here.`

Comment: Check the convections.

Comment: I just copied pasted from the documentation to my main.tf. Even with their modules the command did not pass - ```on main.tf line 142, in module "vpn-prod-internal":
│  142:   vpn_gw_ip               = google_compute_address.vpn_static_ip.address # Public IP address of the VPN Gateway (GCP Reserved IP)
│
│ An argument named "vpn_gw_ip" is not expected here.```

Comment: is difficult if you dont share the full code + the error